# MySQL 'union all' not bringing back information for second select statement

Tags: mysql, union

EDIT: UNION and UNION ALL have the same result.

I have the following statement - I had assumed that this would bring back the following columns

I've realised that I am asking to UNION from the same table, does that matter?  I need to bring back data for 'hotel_name, company, hotel_1 and q351' - is that possible?

**hotel_name, company, hotel_1 and q351**

```
(SELECT hotel_name, company, 
((AVG (q1) + AVG(q2) + AVG(q3) + AVG(q4) + AVG(q5) + AVG(q6) + AVG(q7) + AVG(q8) + AVG(q9) + AVG(q10) + AVG(q11) + AVG(q12) + AVG(q13) + AVG(q14) + AVG(q15) + AVG(q16) + AVG(q17) + AVG(q18) + AVG(q19) + AVG(q20) + AVG(q21) + AVG(q22) + AVG(q23)+ AVG(q24)+ AVG(q25) ) / 25 ) AS hotel_1
FROM thotels_respondents 
LEFT JOIN thotels_results_new ON thotels_respondents.login_id = thotels_results_new.company AND thotels_results_new.sdate = 'NOV2014' 
WHERE thotels_respondents.brand = 'ACME' AND thotels_respondents.sdate = 'NOV2014' AND completion_status = 'Not Started' 
GROUP BY hotel_name 
ORDER BY hotel_name)
UNION ALL
(SELECT hotel_name, company, 
((AVG (q1) + AVG(q2) + AVG(q3) + AVG(q4) + AVG(q5) + AVG(q6) + AVG(q7) + AVG(q8) + AVG(q9) + AVG(q10) + AVG(q11) + AVG(q12) + AVG(q13) + AVG(q14) + AVG(q15) + AVG(q16) + AVG(q17) + AVG(q18) + AVG(q19) + AVG(q20) + AVG(q21) + AVG(q22) + AVG(q23)+ AVG(q24)+ AVG(q25) ) / 25 ) AS q351
FROM thotels_respondents 
LEFT JOIN thotels_results_new ON thotels_respondents.login_id = thotels_results_new.company AND thotels_results_new.sdate = 'NOV2014' 
WHERE q35 = 1 AND thotels_respondents.brand = 'ACME' AND thotels_respondents.sdate = 'NOV2014' AND completion_status = 'Not Started' 
GROUP BY hotel_name 
ORDER BY hotel_name)
```

But it actually, only brings back data for:

**hotel_name, company, hotel_1**

It is missing q351

I can only surmise I am using UNION ALL incorrectly - can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: `UNION ALL` keeps the name of the columns in the first part of the UNION the rest are ignored.Use a dummy value to test `SELECT blah,'UNION1' UNION ALL SELECT someotherblah,'UNION2'`

Comment: Tried with just 'UNION" same result.

Comment: The 3 columns are imposed on on top of each other you can only UNION an exact number of columns.Why do you expect to UNION 2 queries which each return 3 columns and expect to have 4 columns?

Comment: It's really weird the query runs at all. I get "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns" when I try to do the same :-?

Comment: I think its my misunderstanding of what UNION does.  Both statements must bring back the same number of columns, I had assumed (wrongly, clearly) that it would show both hotel_1 and q351 - is what I am trying to achieve possible then?

Comment: Stop. Step away from the terminal. See normalisation.

Comment: Cheers @Strawberry - really, genuinely, appreciated, you go out of your way to help and assist.  I love you man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the different condition from WHERE in the aggregate function

```
SELECT hotel_name, company, 
((AVG (q1) + AVG(q2) + AVG(q3) + AVG(q4) + AVG(q5) + AVG(q6) + AVG(q7) + AVG(q8) + AVG(q9) + AVG(q10) + AVG(q11) + AVG(q12) + AVG(q13) + AVG(q14) + AVG(q15) + AVG(q16) + AVG(q17) + AVG(q18) + AVG(q19) + AVG(q20) + AVG(q21) + AVG(q22) + AVG(q23)+ AVG(q24)+ AVG(q25) ) / 25 ) AS hotel_1,
((AVG (CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q1 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q2 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q3 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q4 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q5 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q6 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q7 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q8 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q9 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q10 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q11 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q12 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q13 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q14 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q15 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q16 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q17 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q18 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q19 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q20 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q21 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q22 END) + AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q23 END)+ AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q24 END)+ AVG(CASE WHEN q35 = 1 THEN  q25 END) ) / 25 ) AS q351
FROM thotels_respondents 
LEFT JOIN thotels_results_new ON thotels_respondents.login_id = thotels_results_new.company AND thotels_results_new.sdate = 'NOV2014' 
WHERE thotels_respondents.brand = 'ACME' AND thotels_respondents.sdate = 'NOV2014' AND completion_status = 'Not Started' 
GROUP BY hotel_name 
ORDER BY hotel_name
```

Comment: many thanks, that's the output I needed.  I'll read up o UNION in more detail as clearly my expectations were incorrect.